# Is there a Google Sheets Formula for Validating Apple IDs (IDFA) and Android IDs (GAID)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

We have a list of consented customers who have agreed to be part of an experiment for a charity.
We are looking for a nice way to let the marketing team validate that they are capturing the right IDFAs and Google Android IDs.

The [Adobe site has a good definition of each](https://helpx.adobe.com/audience-):
Are there any pre-made formuals to validate the following or should I go down the appscript path?
[image: Definition of Device IDS]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to syntactically validate that the input IDs are in the correct structure of a UUID (8-4-4-4-12), you could use regex:

```
=index(if(A1:A<>"",regexmatch(A1:A,"(?i)^[0-9a-f]{8}\-([0-9a-f]{4}\-){3}[0-9a-f]{12}$"),))
```

[image]

I don't know about checking to see if they are actual accounts.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. This was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Sorry I thought I had!